# Using PHP Pthreads with Ratchet Websocket

Tags: php, multithreading, websocket, pthreads, ratchet

I am making an html5 game [www.titansoftime.com](http://www.titansoftime.com)

I am using ratchet as a php websocket server solution. It works great! http://socketo.me/docs/push

I have done several standalone test using the php pthreads extension and have seen some very exciting results. It truly works and works well.. as long as websockets aren't in the mix.

Pthreads give php multithreading capabilities (it really does work and it's amazing). http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

This is what I do:

/src/server.php
This is the file that launches the daemon.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    use MyApp\Pusher;

    require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../mysql.cls.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../game.cls.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../model.cls.php';

    $mysql = new mysql;
    $game  = new game;

    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher();

    $loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.50, function() use($pusher){
        $pusher->load();
    });

    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);

    if ($loop instanceof \React\EventLoop\LibEventLoop) {
        echo "\n HAS LibEvent";
    }

    $webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
            new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                    new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($pusher)
            ),
            $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

This all works fine.

/src/MyApp/Pusher.php
This class pushes data to all connected users.

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;

class AsyncThread extends \Thread{

    public $client;

    public function __construct($client){
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function run(){

        // do work on $this->client
        $user = mysql::assoc('SELECT * from users WHERE connection_id = "'.$this->client->resourceId.'"');
        // etc..
        $this->client->send(json_encode(array('foo'=>'bar')));

    }

}

class Pusher implements MessageComponentInterface{

    public static $clients = array();

    #load
    public static function load(){

        $client_count = count(self::$clients);

        echo "\n\n\n".'Serving to '.$client_count.' clients. '.time();

        $start = $istart = microtime(true);

        if( !count(self::$clients) ){
            if( !mysql_ping() ){
                $game->connect();
            }
        }

        $threads = array();
        foreach( self::$clients as $key => $client ){       

            // HANDLE CLIENT

            // This works just fine, the only problem is that if I have lets say 50 simultaneous users, the people near the end of the clients array will have to wait till the other users have been processed. This is not desirable
            $client->send(json_encode('foo'=>'bar'));

           // So I tried this:
           $threads[$key] = new AsyncThread($client);
           $threads[$key]->start();

           // At this point the AsyncThread class will throw a fatal error complaining about not being able to serialize a closure. 
          // If I dont set "$this->data = $client;" in the thread constructor no error appears but now I cant use the data.

           // Also regardless of whether or not I bind the data in the AsyncThread constructor,
           // the connection disappears if I call "new AsyncThread($client)". I cannot explain this behavior.

        }

    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        global $game;
        if( $msg ){
            $data = json_decode($msg);
            if( $data ){    

                switch( $data->task ){

                    #connect
                    case 'connect':
                        echo "\n".'New connection! ('.$from->resourceId.') '.$from->remoteAddress;
                        self::$clients[] = $from;
                        break;

                    default:
                        self::closeConnection($from);
                        echo "\nNO TASK CLOSING";
                        break;

                }
            }else{
                echo "\n NO DATA";
                self::closeConnection($from);
            }
        }else{
            echo "\n NO MSG";
            self::closeConnection($from);
        }
    }

    public function closeConnection($conn){
        global $game;
        if( $conn ){
            if( $conn->resourceId ){
                $connid = $conn->resourceId;
                $conn->close(); 
                $new = array();
                foreach( self::$clients as $client ){
                    if( $client->resourceId != $connid ){
                        $new[] = $client;
                    }
                }
                self::$clients = $new;
                $game->query('UPDATE users set connection_id = 0 WHERE connection_id = "'.intval($connid).'" LIMIT 1');
                echo "\n".'Connection '.$connid.' has disconnected';
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        echo "\nCLIENT DROPPED";
        self::closeConnection($conn);
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "\nCLIENT ERRORED";
        self::closeConnection($conn);
    }
    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    }
    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    }

}
```

This all works fine as long as I don't create a thread inside the event loop.

Am I going about this the wrong way or is php multithreading and websockets incompatible?

Comment: Hobbes do you have updates for this questions?

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer lol.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to implement multithreading, if you went through ratchet's and react's source then you will understanding that it is using no-blocking socket read functions. Also, if you want a small amount of performance boost then you might want to look into libevent.

Comment: I use libevent. I think the only way to use React the way you are stating in my app is to create an event loop for each connection. That sounds messy, but I'll mess with it.

Comment: Any news on this approach? I need to write at the same time to different web socket clients continuously (because data is generated continuously for each specific ip:port pair) and Ratchet does not work well with this case (it basically waits you to end onMessage to return data to the client, so any other message cannot be processed).

Comment: Not yet man, hopefully I can figure out something.

Comment: Hobbes do you found a solution to this? facing the serialization problems for days now

Answer (score 1):

check this package https://github.com/huyanping/react-multi-process

**Install**

composer require jenner/react-multi-process
How to use it?

So simple like:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$server = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:4020');
stream_set_blocking($server, 0);
$loop->addReadStream($server, function ($server) use ($loop) {
    $conn = stream_socket_accept($server);
    $data = "pid:" . getmypid() . PHP_EOL;
    $loop->addWriteStream($conn, function ($conn) use (&$data, $loop) {
        $written = fwrite($conn, $data);
        if ($written === strlen($data)) {
            fclose($conn);
            $loop->removeStream($conn);
        } else {
            $data = substr($data, 0, $written);
        }
    });
});

// the second param is the sub process count
$master = new \React\Multi\Master($loop, 20);
$master->start();
```

An example using jenner/simple_fork like:

```
class IoServer {
     /**
     * @param int $count worker process count
     * Run the application by entering the event loop
     * @throws \RuntimeException If a loop was not previously specified
     */
    public function run($count = 1) {
        if (null === $this->loop) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("A React Loop was not provided during instantiation");
        }

        if($count <= 1){
            $this->loop->run();
        }else{
            $loop = $this->loop;
            $master = new \Jenner\SimpleFork\FixedPool(function() use($loop) {
                $this->loop->run();
            }, $count);
            $master->start();
            $master->keep(true);
//            or just 
//            $master = new \React\Multi\Master($this->loop, $count);
//            $master->start();
        }
    }
}
```